# Какое регулярное выражение использовать для тэга переноса строки?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Текст в HTML:

```
<div class='text'>Статья 46.<br/<br/>1. Каждому гарантируется судебная защита его прав и свобод.<br/>2. Решения и действия должностных лиц могут быть обжалованы в суд.</div>
```

Каждый символ имеющегося текста заключается в span, кроме переноса строки. Код такой:

```
text = $('.text').text();
letters = text.split('');
$('.text').html(text.replace(/\S|\w|\s/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>'));
```

Как исправить регулярное выражение, чтобы все переносы строк учитывались и заключались в отдельный `span`, как и остальные символы?

Comment: https://www.regex101.com/r/cX4fF0/1 ?  MATCH 60

Comment: Я бы посоветовал не использовать чередования, раз уж все-все символы нужно заключить в тег, символьные классы надёжнее и быстрее. [`[\s\S]`](https://www.regex101.com/r/cX4fF0/2) должно сработать. Если `$('.text').html(text.replace(/[\S\s]/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>'))` не работает, что-то не так с кодом.

Comment: Бесполезно. <br/> не считывает, текст без переноса в итоге. Испробовано и [\s\S], и (\S|\w|\s|\n). Что-то не так, видимо. Не могу понять что.

Comment: Сделайте `console.log(text)` там все увидите

Comment: @ReinRaus Не выдаёт ошибки. В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое решение:

```
text = $('.text').html() 
letters = text.split('')
$('.text').html(text.replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>|\S/gi, '<span class="letter">$&</span>'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема исходит из того, что `jQuery.text()` не преобразует `<BR/>` в перевод строки. В тексте из-за этого просто нет этих самых переводов строки, которые Вы ищете.
Найти их можно заменив все `<BR/>` на переводы строк таким способом (к примеру):

```
$( '.text br' ).replaceWith( "\n" );
```

Сниппет ниже демонстрирует как это отразится на результате:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '.text br' ).replaceWith( "\n" );
  text = $( '.text' ).text();
  console.log(text);
  letters = text.split('');
  text = text.replace(/[\S\s]/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>');
  console.log( text.replace( "\n", "I am linebreak!" ) );
  $('.text').html( text );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='text'>1234<br/><br/>1234<br/>1234</div>
```

---

Хоть проблема была и не в регулярном выражении, но объясню в чем некрасивость выражения

```
/\S|\w|\s/g
```

Его нужно читать так:

- не пробелы, или
- буква, или
- пробелы

Но это же ничто иное как абсолютно все символы, а значит лучше упростить:

```
/[\S\s]/g
```

Comment: В этом решении теряется исходное форматирование текста. Получилось через jQuery.html() и `replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>|\S/gi,...)`

Comment: @Stacy_Pro то есть Вам нужно, чтобы тэги br заключались, а не переносы строк? Тогда Вам следует писать конкретные вопросы. В вопросе написано про «переносы строк», а хотите «тэги br ». Это разные вещи.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Никакое, потому что `<br>` - это тег, следовательно после вызова метода `text()` от него в строке уже ничего не осталось и как-либо искать его бесполезно.

```
$("<div class='text'>Статья 46.<br/><br/>1. Каждому гарантируется судебная защита его прав и свобод.<br/>2. Решения и действия должностных лиц могут быть обжалованы в суд.</div>")
.text().indexOf(" 46.1. ") // 6
```

Answer (score -1):

Тут нужно различать переносы строк в текст (\r\n) и переносы строк в html ( тег br).

В вашем html есть только html переносы. Если добавить текстовые переносы, то работать будет так:

```
<div class='text'>Статья 46.<br/><br/>
1. Каждому гарантируется судебная защита его прав и свобод.<br/>
2. Решения и действия должностных лиц могут быть обжалованы в суд.</div>
```

И измененная команда:

```
$('.text').html(text.replace(/\S|\w|\s|\n|\r/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>'))
```

Теги br пропадают из текста благодаря следующей команде

```
text = $('.text').text()
```

Чтобы их не терять, можно преобразовать так

```
text = $(".text").html().replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
letters = text.split('')
$('.text').html(text.replace(/\S|\w|\s|\n|\r/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>'))
```

Можно изменить так, чтобы итоговое форматирование сохранялось:

```
text = $(".text").html().replace(/<br>/gi, "\n");
text = text.replace(/\S|\w|\s/g, '<span class="letter">$&</span>')
text = text.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<span class="letter"><br /></span>')
$('.text').html(text)
```

Comment: <br> в span обернулся - уже хорошо. Вывод текста всё равно в одну строку - пробел вместо переноса.

Comment: Поясните про вывод в одну строчку... Можно заменять \n на тег br вторым реплейсом

Comment: Так выглядит:
Статья 46. 1. Каждому гарантируется судебная защита его прав и свобод. 2.       На месте переноса пробел. Но при этом для каждого свой span, как и надо.

Comment: Добавил исправления

Comment: @Stacy_Pro я так понимаю, что мой ответ не удовлетворил каким-то запросам?

Comment: После повторного реплейса оборачивания в спаны нет.

Comment: Я не понимаю, что вы хотите в итоге. Если будут spanы - это то, что нужно?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы каждый символ - и буква, и перенос строки - в итоге были обёрнуты в span для дальнейшей работы с ними по отдельности. Текст же должен отображаться с переносами строк, в том виде, в котором задан изначально.

Comment: Можно заменить строку на text = text.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<span class="letter"><br /></span>')